# Как проверить папку на наличие каких-либо файлов, с помощью Gulp?

Tags: gulp, node.js

И дальше в зависимости от условия есть файлы в папке какие-то или нету запускать задачу

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать плагин [gulp-newer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-newer), он сравнивает директорию с исходниками и директорию "на выход" и если файлы одинаковые, то он их не пропускает, а значит задача будет завершаться в разы быстрей.
Но задачу запускать он будет так или сяк, потому, что чтоб запустить проверку, нужно запустить задачу :)

Так можно использовать [gulp-if](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-if) и [stream-combiner2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stream-combiner2), но этот вариант сложней и там можно будет сделать сравнение по имени файлов и т.д, только вы должны понимать как работает потоки в nodejs и потоки в vinyl-fs.

Еще можно использовать **gulp-if** для того, чтоб менять режим работы в галпе.
Например вы можете создать переменную

```
const isDevelopment = process.env.NODE_ENV || process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development';
```

а в самом таске уже

```
gulp.task('styles', () => 
  gulp.src('./styles/main.css')
  .pipe(gulpIf(isDevelopment, sourcemaps.init())
  .pipe(gulpif(isDevelopment, sourcemaps.write())
  .pipe(gulp.dest())
)
```

Передавать в запуск
для window
`set NODE_ENV=production&&gulp`
для linux
`NODE_ENV=production && gulp`
и сравнивания переменную, sourcemaps будут/не будут прогоняться через поток.

**Еще можно использовать fs.access например, для проверки наличия файла, есть и другие способы, но я написал более мне понятный.**
Структура файлов в папке app/assets/img/

```
ASSETS
└───img
        chart-1.png
        chart-2.png
```

Структура файлов в папке dist

```
DIST\IMG
    chart-1.png
    chart-2.png

const fs = require('fs'); //встроенная библиотека fs
const map = require('map-stream'); // Чтоб пройтись мапом по файлам
const path = require('path'); // Для создания путей
const allowFiles = ['chart-1.png']; // Массив с именами файлов которые нам нужны

gulp.task('check-it', () => 
    gulp.src('./app/assets/**/*.png')
        .pipe(map((file, next) => {
            if (allowFiles.includes(file.basename)) { // первая проверка на совпадение имени
                fs.access(path.join(process.cwd(),'dist', file.relative), (err) => { // проверка на существования файла
                    if (!err || err.code !== 'ENOENT') { // Проверяю наличие ошибки или отсутствие ошибок всех кроме 'ENOENT' (файл не существует)
                        console.log('HAVE FILE: ', file.basename)
                        next(null); // Файл есть, значит ничего не пишем.
                    } else {
                        console.log('not have file ', file.basename);
                        next(null, file); // Файла нет, значит пишем
                    }
                })
            } else {
                next(null, file);  // Если имя не совпало, то пропускаем файлы дальше.
            }
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
);
```

Comment: Вы не совсем поняли суть вопроса, мне нужно ПРОВЕРЯТЬ лежат ли какие файлы в папке или нет и вопрос в том как это сделать.

Comment: Ну вы можете использовать fs.access которые проверяет наличие файла и прав на него и если файла нет, то выдаст ошибку.
Я дописал ниже свой ответ.